# How do I get pip to install a specific version of meld?

Tags: python, pip, meld

While trying to follow this guide https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1496 I am trying to get supervisor to generate its conf file, but it fails because it needs meld3>=0.6.5 and apparently meld3 1.0.2 doesn't count. Having tried various solutions on https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1492 I am wanting to follow pbylina's suggestion of downgrading to meld3 1.0.0, but unlike pbylina I get errors when I try to install that version of meld:

```
# pip install meld3==1.0.0
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting meld3==1.0.0
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading meld3-1.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zhFMlS/meld3/
```

How do I downgrade from meld 1.0.2 to 1.0.0?

Comment: You can uninstall the current package and then install the 1.0.0 version.

Comment: Same error after uninstalling meld:
    # pip uninstall meld3
    -- snip --
      Successfully uninstalled meld3-1.0.2
    # pip install meld3==1.0.0
    -- snip --
        
        error: invalid command 'egg_info'
        
        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jyN3N1/meld3/